# Multiparty encryption and decryption

Tags: encryption, public-key

Is it possible to send a single encrypted data message to multiple users so that the users receiving the message can only decrypt certain parts of the message, depending on their rights.

For example, I send a message "Hello World", User A could decrypt and receive the whole message(hello world), but user B could only decrypt a certain part and receive the message as "hello" only.

Comment: You could trivially do this if you just encrypt "hello world" using A's public key and "hello" using B's public key and send both ciphertexts to both A and B. However, I expect this is not what you are after. Probably you want some additional properties of the scheme. Could you maybe describe those properties? Public-key encryption has many exotic variants so probably what you are looking for exists.

Comment: For example, it is not clear how "distributed decryption" factors in to your question although you used that tag.

Comment: I removed the distributed decryption tag, because as described this is not the same thing at all. Feel free to [edit] and add back if you can describe how it relates to your question.

Comment: Cross-posted from [so]: [multiparty encryption and decryption](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35126246/1816580)

Answer (score 1):

This is - *in a way* - **Functional Encryption**.

From Wikipedia:

> Functional encryption is a type of public-key encryption in which
>   possessing a secret key allows one to learn a function of what the
>   ciphertext is encrypting.

So, **YES**, it is possible.

For more information [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/543.pdf) paper might prove useful.

Comment: It's important to note that there currently no such construction for arbitrary $f$. Even predicate encryption works only on inner-products and doesn't come even close.